# SharePoint Link with QueryString Parameters

Tags: sharepoint

The task is to migrate classic ASP functionality to SharePoint Server 2013.

On the ASP page, a certain link is visible only if the authenticated user's password can be retrieved from a database. The link looks similar to:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.someurl.com/secure/login.php?username=<%=strUserName%>&password=<%=rsOpenOrders("CL_password")%>" onmouseover="self.status=' '; return true;">
<img border="0" src="somelogo.gif" width="267" height="80" /></a>
```

I'm new to SharePoint, and I would appreciate your help (conceptual and code snippet) in solving this problem.

I understand that writing "code behind" is not highly encouraged with SharePoint pages and web parts.

So, what's the best alternative to be able to use the authenticated username value in building the first querystring parameter, and to query a SQLServer database to retrieve the value for the second querystring parameter? Please ignore the security concern here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its called `SPSecurityTrimmedControl`

example:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>  
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" runat="server"  
AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly" Permissions="ManageWeb" PermissionContext="CurrentSite">  
    <INCLUDE OUR CONTROL / CONTENT HERE>  
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating custom web parts developed using Visual Studio 2013 for each particular link that needed query string parameters to be built based on values retrieved from database.